# HTML Как ссылаться на внешний код?

Tags: html, jquery

Вопрос такой, что даже и примерно не знаю бывает ли такое))

Суть в том, что у меня многостраничный сайт и на всех страницах имеется одна и та же шапка меню, так вот, можно как то прописать один раз это меню и его свойства в одном файле, а во на всех остальных только ссылаться на него, чтобы оно отображалось?

Мне это нужно для того, чтобы когда мне нужно добавить новые номинации в меню не переписывать 100500 страниц, имеющих эту шапку. И да, что важно, сайт будет находиться локально на компьютере, т.е. не на сервере!

P.s. 
Я попробовал jQuery и вот мой код:

```
<div id="a"></div>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hello");
    $("#a").load("Menu.html");

    });
</script>
```

И даже эта вещь не работает, почему то... В чем подвох и как вообще можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: "не работает" - что это значит?

Comment: @igor, Не выводит содержимое меню на странице

Comment: Вы партизан? советский разведчик? кому это надо? `alert` появляется?

Comment: В консоли браузера есть ошибки?

Comment: Попробуй подключить шаблонизатор - [TWIG](https://twig.symfony.com/)

Comment: А вы не пробовали аджакс?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону шаблонизаторов. Они как раз для этого и созданы, чтобы не переписывать по много раз одно и то же. Создадите базовый шаблон, в котором подключите шапку, подвал и все общие для всех страниц элементы. А уже на каждой странице напишете их индивидуальную часть. Из шаблонизаторов от простого к сложному (по одному из мнений) выбор следующий:

- [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)
- [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [Dust](http://www.dustjs.com/)
- [Pug](https://pugjs.org/)
- И другие (список .

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо за подсказку! Я изучил Mustache, но никак не могу понять почему не работает код:{{name}} в теле html? Библиотеку подключил все хорошо, а вот это нууу никак не работет)

Answer (score 0):

Технически можно использовать iframe т.е. вместо вашего меню вставлять iframe с ссылкой на него. Пример реализации можно глянуть тут - http://ecufa.ru/ (боковушки). Использовать этот способ или нет, уже вам решать.